# Deleting files in a gulp task

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I have a gulp task in which I want to take some source files and copy them to `build/premium` and `build/free` and then remove some extra files from
`build/free`.

My attempt at that was doing this:

```
gulp.task("build", ["clean"], function () {
  gulp.src(["src/*", "!src/composer.*", "LICENSE"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/premium"))
    .pipe(del(["build/free/plugins/*", "!build/free/plugins/index.php"]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/free"));
});
```

Which results in an error:

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Stream.pipe (stream.js:45:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/gezim/projects/myproj/gulpfile.js:9:6)
```

How do I accomplish this the deleting port? Is there a better way altogether to do this?

Comment: I don't get the order of the operations here. The intent seems to be to delete files (`.pipe(del(..))`) that have not been copied yet (`.pipe(gulp.dest("build/free"))`). Is there a reason `del` should be before the `pipe` that copies to `build/free`?

Comment: @Louis I had it delete after copying but that didn't work either. I guess I thought delete from pipe, which makes no sense in hindsight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use `gulp-filter` to drop only what should not be copied from the 2nd destination.

I interpreted the intent of the task as wanting everything present in `src` to be present in `build/premium`. However, `build/free` should exclude everything which was originally in `src/plugins` but should still include `src/plugins/index.php`.

Here is a working gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var filter = require("gulp-filter");
var del = require("del");

gulp.task("clean", function () {
  return del("build");
});

gulp.task("build", ["clean"], function () {
  return gulp.src(["src/**", "!src/composer.*", "LICENSE"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/premium"))
    .pipe(filter(["**", "!plugins/**", "plugins/index.php"]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/free"));
});
```

The patterns passed to `filter` are *relative* paths. Since the `gulp.src` pattern has `src/**` it means they are relative to `src`.

Note also that `del` cannot be passed straight to `.pipe()` as it returns a promise. It can be returned from a task, like the `clean` task does.

Comment: Thanks so much. This was spot on.

Answer (score 17):

This is a simple `clean` task implementation with `gulp-del`:

```
var del = require('gulp-del');

gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del(['folderA/js', 'folderA/css', 'folderB/js']);
});
```

In your case you can just call it after build (read "use build as a dependency"):

```
gulp.task("build", function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/*', '!src/composer.*', 'LICENSE'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/premium"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/free"));
});

gulp.task("complete-build", ["build"] function(){
  return del(['build/free/plugins/*', '!build/free/plugins/index.php']);
});
```

Then call the "complete-build" task to perform it.
To be honest this is more a "Grunt"-like approach to the problem, but done with Gulp. Perhaps the recommendation to filter things before writing them in the `build/free` folder is more in the Gulp spirit.

#### Update 2/2018

The delete module has been renamed to `del` now as reported by @gerl:

```
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del(['folderA/js', 'folderA/css', 'folderB/js']);
});
```

Comment: I only want to remove things from `build/free` once stuff is copied to it. Having `clean` as you have makes it run before `build` runs.

Comment: I've updated the code to do what you want. Perhaps it's better to use a pro-active filter instead of writing & delete.

Comment: it is now `require('del')`

Comment: The latest version of del uses ESM, so you need version 6 for this answer to work. In your `package.json` put `"del": "^6.1.1"`